# How to make a simple HTTPS server in Python 3x

Tags: python, ssl, https, request, slack

How can i create the simpliest python server, which will receive just one response and than die?

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19706670/22221987), but modified it a bit, because of deprecation of some methods.

```py
import http.server
from ssl import SSLContext


class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        print(post_data.decode('utf-8'))

server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)

httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = SSLContext().wrap_socket(sock=httpd.socket,
                                        server_side=True,
                                        do_handshake_on_connect=False,
                                        suppress_ragged_eofs=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

But it doesn't work.

```
C:\Users\mikha\Desktop\Mika\Projects\yummy_slack\test_1.py:14: DeprecationWarning: ssl.SSLContext() without protocol argument is deprecated.
  httpd.socket = SSLContext().wrap_socket(sock=httpd.socket,
C:\Users\mikha\Desktop\Mika\Projects\yummy_slack\test_1.py:14: DeprecationWarning: ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS is deprecated
  httpd.socket = SSLContext().wrap_socket(sock=httpd.socket,
----------------------------------------
Exception occurred during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 51828)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\socketserver.py", line 316, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\socketserver.py", line 347, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\server.py", line 668, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\server.py", line 433, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\server.py", line 401, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1274, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1130, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: NO_SHARED_CIPHER] no shared cipher (_ssl.c:2578)
----------------------------------------
```

And this error continues for a bunch of ports in a row.

I'm not a genius in networks, but really trying to understand what's going wrong here.

The main task is to receive the redirected response from Slack OAuth link.

**UPD**:
I've tried to use certificate and key, when starting server. But script stucks on `load_cert_chain`. No crashes or something.

I've used this command to create a certificate and key `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`
Here the example:

```
import http.server
import ssl


class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        print(post_data.decode('utf-8'))


server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 5000)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="cert.pem", keyfile="key.pem")

httpd.socket = context.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: But than Slack can't send the verification code as answer. It works only with `https` url.

Comment: I think you may be better off with Flask.

Comment: @Reinderien but i still need to handle with SSl there. It's a easier solution, using `    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc")` in Flask, but this is not a good practice, since this is generating certificate and key on fly, which is not good for using in browser (bc it will warn user about unsecured connection every time)

Comment: Right; so... where is the certificate in your code? You haven't added one, either.

Comment: @Reinderien, i've updated the question. ADded certificate and key, but still nothing. Server just doesn't walk up.

Comment: Your last script worked for me, with the only difference being I referred to the certFile and keyFile locations by their full path.

Answer (score 0):

To create simple HTTPS server you can use this example:

```py
import http.server
import ssl


def get_ssl_context(certfile, keyfile):
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
    context.set_ciphers("@SECLEVEL=1:ALL")
    return context


class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers["Content-Length"])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        print(post_data.decode("utf-8"))


server_address = ("127.0.0.1", 5000)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)

context = get_ssl_context("cert.pem", "key.pem")
httpd.socket = context.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

The `cert.pem` and `key.pem` are created using this command:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

**Note:** Don't forget to set `Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []` to `127.0.0.1` !

Running this script will create server running on `127.0.0.1:5000`.

---

To test it you can send from other terminal this command:

```
curl --cacert cert.pem -X POST -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" https://127.0.0.1:5000
```

Comment: `ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2` is deprecated so you should use `context = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_2_METHOD)`